# Attempt to create proxy for a non-annotation type

Tags: java, reflection, proxy, annotations

Why do I get `java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Attempt to create proxy for a non-annotation type.` when I'm trying to get the annotation list from the field?

My annotation:

```
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
private @interface TypicalAnnotation
{
    int size();
}
```

Usage:

```
public static class MockAnnotatedClass
{
    @TypicalAnnotation(size = 3)
    public Integer number = 2;
}
```

Call:

```
ReflectionUtils.getAllFields(clazz1).getAnnotations() <- got the exception.
```

Comment: From what library do you get `ReflectionUtils` ?

Comment: Spring commons. I dont get any exceptions for example if I use @Deprecated annotation from core java.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I used Jdeveloper 12.2.1.0.0 and integrated Weblogic with enabled Fast Swap feature.

if you look at the source code ([github](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/reflect/annotation/AnnotationInvocationHandler.java)) you will see that an exception is thrown if the type is either not an annotation or implements more than one interface or does not implement the java.lang.annotation.Annotation interface:

```
AnnotationInvocationHandler(Class<? extends Annotation> type, Map<String, Object> memberValues) {
    Class<?>[] superInterfaces = type.getInterfaces();
    if (!type.isAnnotation() ||
        superInterfaces.length != 1 ||
        superInterfaces[0] != java.lang.annotation.Annotation.class)
        throw new AnnotationFormatError("Attempt to create proxy for a non-annotation type.");
    this.type = type;
    this.memberValues = memberValues;
}
```

Using this code, I checked which interfaces my annotation implements:

Annotation declaration:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {}
```

Checking of type:

```
Class<?> type = MyAnnotation.class;

System.out.println("type.isAnnotation() " + type.isAnnotation());
System.out.println("type.getInterfaces().length " + type.getInterfaces().length);

for (Class<?> superType : type.getInterfaces()) {
    System.out.println("type.getInterfaces()[i] " + superType);
}
```

Output:

```
type.isAnnotation() true
type.getInterfaces().length 2
type.getInterfaces()[i] interface java.lang.annotation.Annotation
type.getInterfaces()[i] interface com.bea.wls.redef.Redefinable     // << ??????
```

As it turned out, another interface is added to the annotation.
I did not find information specifically about com.bea.wls.redef.Redefinable. After a bit of searching, I realized that the package com.bea.wls.redef is used by the Fast Swap function.

I see 2 solutions:

1. Disable Fast Swap function.
2. Move all custom annotations to separate jar. It is what I did.

Perhaps there is a way to turn off wrapping for annotations. But I did not find it.